# NavigationView in ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-layout

I was going to use NavigationView instead of rolling my own in my DrawerLayout, but instead of using NavView's menu structure I am using my own ListView within the NavView tag. IOW, I do have an app:headerLayout in NavView but do not have an app:menu attribute.

This works as far as the drawer opening and closing and shows my list as expected with the two following glitches: it slides in *below* my ActionBar and the header is not displayed. The header is in the layout and I can find its IDs, but it is not shown.

So is what I am trying to do possible? The only real reason I am trying to use NavView is that it handles the drawer width properly, but I can live without that if I can't get the rest of it to display as I wish.

Comment: The drawer width should be handled correctly by `DrawerLayout` whether or not you use a `NavigationView`

Comment: You are correct. I guess I had only seen DrawerLayout examples with specific widths set (e.g. "260dp") and then read something about NavigationView that implied that handling the correct width was a specific enhancement of that widget.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use `listview` inside the `navigationView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/main_toolbar" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/menuList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

you can not use `app:header` and `app:menu` as you are using listview. You have to create header manually.